# Minimal polynomial - Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $D$ be the differentiation operator on $P(\mathbb{R})$, the space of polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$.  Prove that there exists no polynomial $g(t)$ for which $g(D) = 0$.

Hence $D$ has no minimal polynomial.

Comment: Have you tried anything to prove this?

Comment: No,  I m not getting if how to start. Please help!

Answer (score 4):

Suppose there was such a polynomial $g(t)$. Let $n = \text{degree}(g)$. Then $g(D)(x^{n+1}) \neq 0$, a contradiction.

Comment: You should write down the details of why $g(D)(x^{n+1}) \neq 0$.